# unknown error the function 'scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &sent);'

Tags: c, output, scanf, format-specifiers

Getting to point, I am a beginner in the C language and just encountered a weird method of **inputting string** in a C Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char ch, string[100], sent[100];
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    scanf("%s", &string);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &sent);

    printf("%c\n", ch);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    printf("%s", sent);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error: the last line (Sentence) doesn't print, no idea where I am wrong, but on research I found this code:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", &sent); //not theres a space before %[^\n]%*c; and then it worked (wtf)
```

can you explain why it worked by just adding a space there.

Comment: That's because the `*` after each specifier`%` tells `scanf` not to store the result. Compiler says *"Warning C4474: 'scanf' : too many arguments passed for format string."*

Comment: @WeatherVane but how does putting 1 space before "%*[^\n]%*c" solve everything, after putting the space the code works flawlessly

Comment: I don't know: the compiler still gives a warning. Aside: `&string` and `&sent` should be `string` and `sent` anyway. Anyway, without saying what you entered it's impossible to comment on what "flawless" means.

Comment: i am practicing this code on hacker rank , i understand "&" should not be there but without it ,  their compiler shows error

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour. It attempts to print a string that was not initialised.

Comment: please explain **undefined**

Comment: It means what Wikipedia says about [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You can't fix one problem by adding another error.

Comment: Who or what text suggested `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c",...);`?

Comment: **In order to take a line as input, you can use scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s); **  source: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/playing-with-characters/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: Note that `scanf("%s", string);` leaves a newline in the buffer, and `scanf("%[^\n]", sent);` will read nothing, because it stops at that newline, however, adding the space tells it to filter the newline.

Comment: i know an alternative  using gets(); but it is not working  (compiler error)

Comment: But `%[^\n]` does not contain any `*`, unlike the question posted.

Comment: It's bad advice from Hacker Rank to advise removing a trailing newline, because there might not be one. OTOH it's good to filter leading whitespace, because it doesn't have to be there.

Comment: after going through some of the answers   they have used scanf("\n");  before scanf("%[^\n]%*c",sent);   whats the purpose of scanf("\n");?   i guess i am done here  thanks for the answer

Comment: Now you have corrected the question, please read my comment which starts "Note that `scanf` ..."

Comment: that was causing the undefined error i suppose  ,  thanks for explaining why we use Space before %[^\n]%*c

Comment: Note that the compiler should be complaining about both `scanf("%s",&string);` and `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&sent);` — in both, the `&` is incorrect because it passes a `char (*)[100]` where `scanf()` is told to expect a `char *`.  If your compiler doesn't complain, you've not cranked the warning levels high enough, or you need a better compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space () in the format string causes scanf to skip whitespace in the input.  Its normally not needed, as most scanf conversions ALSO skip whitespace before they scan anything, but the two that do not are `%c` and `%[` -- so using a space before `%[` has a visible effect.  Lets look at what your 3 scanf calls do:

```
scanf("%c",&ch);           // read the next character into 'ch'
scanf("%s",&string);       // skip whitespace, then read non-whitespac characters
                           // into 'string', stopping when the first whitespace after
                           // some non-whitespace is reached (that last whitespace
                           // will NOT be read, being left as the next character
                           // of the input.)
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&sent);  // read non-newline characters into 'sent', up until a
                           // newline, then read and discard 1 character
                           // (that newline)
```

So the 3rd scanf will start reading with the whitespace that ended the second scanf.  If you add a space to the start of the format, it will instead read and discard whitespace until it finds a non-whitespace character, then start reading into `sent` with that non-whitespace character.

Also of interest is what happens if the whitespace that ends the second scanf happens to be a newline.  In that case, the thrid scanf will fail completely (as there are no non-newline characters to be read before the newline) and do nothing.  Adding the space here to the third scanf ensures that it does not fial due to the newline (it will be discarded as whitespace), so it will always read something into `sent`, unless an EOF is reached.

Comment: You might also point that `&` on `&string` and `&sent` is harmless but incorrect, and using conversion formats `"%99s"` and `" %99[^\n]%*c"` would be safer, as well as testing the return values.